# Prove the Complex identity

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that $x^8-2x^4cos4\theta+1= \prod_r[x^2-2xcos(\theta+\frac{r}{\pi/2})+1], r=0, 1, 2, 3$, where x is a complex number.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^8-2x^4cos4\theta+1=0$ then $x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}=2cos4\theta $. We have to find the eight roots $\alpha_r$ of the first equation. Then $$x^8-2x^4cos4\theta+1=\prod(x-\alpha_r), r=0,1,2,3,...7$$